# Excel: Apply a formula to a column to "print" a row

Tags: excel

I'm having data set up as:

```
 A1
 A2
 A3
```

and so forth and I want to make a formula in Excel which present them row-wise instead:

```
 A1  A2   A3
```

How do I do this? I've tried to use the formula

```
=$A1
```

And drag that out, but it simply presents the data as $A$1 (i.e. it simply copies the value in A1 into all columns of the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COPY` all your data and `PASTE as TRANSPOSE`, simple as that ;)

You can find more information here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/transpose-excel-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa/

*EDIT: I might have misunderstood the question. If I did let me know and I will remove my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This was certainly an easy way to achieve the desired result. I've updated the question to reflect some problems that arised.

Answer (score 2):

You need `=TRANSPOSE()` formula, but it's tricky:

1. Enter `=TRANSPOSE(A1:A3)` to cell say `B1`.
2. Select three cells with a mouse: `B1:D1`.
3. Press F2 key and enter edit mode.
4. Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Voila!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've updated the question as some problems arised though.